# Sessions not working if directory name starts with "ads"

Tags: php, session, safari, mamp

Really weird bug.  I'm running MAMP Pro on my development computer, and I have a really simple test PHP program that looks like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  var_dump($_SESSION);
```

And the program works where ever I put it on my server, dumping out the session variables.  UNLESS, the directory name starts with "ads" (then it just outputs an empty array).

```
http://domain/test.php - works
http://domain/ads/test.php - doesn't work
http://domain/adtest/test.php - works
http://domain/adserve/test.php - doesn't work
http://domain/sads/test.php - works
```

I don't have any .htaccess file doing anything with "ads".

Update: I did some more testing and found that this is only happening with Safari (not in Chrome or Firefox).  But Safari is the main browser that would be used for this site.  I don't want to change the name of the entire directory just to squirm around some Safari quirk if I don't have to.  I've tried restarting Safari with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps you have some form of adblocker enabled in Safari. Test without it. And btw, keep the `/ads/` path so everone elses adblocker has it easier.

Comment: I thought of that as well and nope… standard stock Safari.  I even tried turning off the "Block cookies from third parties and advertisers" in Safari's preferences and it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

sessions in php use cookie so you need to check if your your safari browser allowing cookies and send a session id cookie back to the server

Comment: Like I said… it works on almost every page.  So yes… cookies are working.

Comment: ok so you can try to add this line after the session_start() $_SESSION['test'] = 'foo'; and then delete the line and refresh the page to see if it see the test var

Comment: So yes… it stores "foo" even after I delete that line.  So it's treating anything starting with "ads" as its own separate site?

Comment: Safari have different policies from other browsers regard to cookies "Safari ships with a conservative cookie policy which limits cookie writes to only the pages chosen ("navigated to") by the user"

Answer (score 0):

So when I wasn't experiencing this in any other browser, including Safari on other machines, I just deleted all the related cookies from the Safari on my development machine, and everything started working again.  No idea what would cause the bug, but at least it was an easy enough fix in the end.

Edit: the problem came back a few days later, so I had to delete cookies again.  I certainly hope this doesn't happen on others' browsers.